# Count the number of object

Tags: python

I am using below code to print the `obj.key`, however I want to count the number of objects generated. Could you please help?

Code used:

```
for obj in buck.objects.filter(Prefix=recent_ocr_path): 
 if obj.size > 0:  # Verifying presence of files
  print(obj.key)
```

Output received using above command:

```
Profile_2022/02/08/16/cdd-kinesis-to-s3-prod-3-2022-02-08-16-00-00-4594cf63
Profile_2022/02/08/16/cdd-kinesis-to-s3-prod-3-2022-02-08-16-00-04-82b265de
Profile_2022/02/08/16/cdd-kinesis-to-s3-prod-3-2022-02-08-16-00-07-66179192
Profile_2022/02/08/16/cdd-kinesis-to-s3-prod-3-2022-02-08-16-00-11-713879f1
```

I am looking for command to display output as "4".

Answer (score 1):

```
counter = 0
for obj in buck.objects.filter(Prefix=recent_ocr_path): 
 if obj.size > 0:  # Verifying presence of files
  counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#use can use the gt filter for size and use count method
bucks=buck.objects.filter(Prefix=recent_ocr_path, size__gt=0)
count=bucks.count()
print(count)
```